# When does the '.finally' block run in async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-finally

So I have a function that encloses an async computation to ensure at the end of the computation, something happens (like releasing certain resources).

so the function goes like

```js
const withinScope = async(fn)=>{
  try{
    return fn()
  }finally{
    await releaseResources()
  }
}
```

Yet, the releaseResources method is never invoked!

Now, if I rewrite it like this:

```js
const withinScope = async(fn)=>{
  try{
    const result = await fn()
    return result
  }finally{
    await releaseResources()
  }
}
```

it works... I kind of get why, but I'd say that's definitely a bug. But is it? or is it the intended behaviour?

Comment: The answer to questions like that in the modern world is almost, almost always "no".

Comment: `releaseResources` is invoked in both examples, but it runs immediately after the `fn()` call without waiting for it to complete in the first.

Comment: the `releaseResources` is always executed.

Comment: Thanks, I realized it too after making the question. Weird thing is that the released resources could still be used even though they were released almost immediately

Comment: It depends on what `fn()` is and whether it's creating a closure over the 'resources'.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. This is behaving as expected. If you do not await an async method, the program will not wait for it to complete before continuing. Try

```js
const withinScope = async(fn)=>{
  try{
    return await fn()
  }finally{
    await releaseResources()
  }
```